# Fix-sized Concurrent list

Tags: c#, list, concurrency

I have implemented a simple task to create a fixed sized list that allows concurrent writes and can dump the latest snapshot of items in the list at any time.

Here is my implementation. The offset will increase atomically for each thread and reset if reaches to the size of the list. Different threads should have isolated access to each section of the array.

My question is when I call Dump(), the first few items are not stored in the list. Also, is there a Interlocked function that can do both atomic increase and reset, so I don't have to create a locker object and a lock block? Thanks.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{            
    ConcurrentCircularFixedList<int> list = new ConcurrentCircularFixedList<int>(20);
    Enumerable.Range(1, 30).AsParallel().Select(nu => list.Enqueu(nu)).ToList();    
}

public class ConcurrentCircularFixedList<T>
{
    private int _size;
    private int _offset;
    private sealed object _locker = new Object();
    privateT[] _list;

    public ConcurrentCircularFixedList(int size)
    {
        _size = size;
        _offset = 0;
        _list = new T[_size];
    }

    public int Enqueu(T item)
    {
        _list[_offset] = item;
        lock(_locker)
        {
            Debug.Write("B " + _offset);
            _offset += 1;
            if(_offset == _size)
                _offset = 0;
            Debug.Write("A " + _offset + "\n");
         }  
         return _offset;
    }

    public T[] Dump()
    {
        return _list.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no lock on `Dump` however I do not believe either lock is necessary.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this belongs in CR.

Comment: @BrianRasmussen, you guys are quick, I hit the submit button by mistake. Please see my questions.

Comment: @Aron, in my Dump method, I called ToArray(), it should create a new array, so I don't think a lock is necessary.

Comment: @Helic, how do you think the array is created? What behavior do you want?

Comment: Your code isn't thread safe. When running concurrently, this code throw `IndexOutOfRangeException`

Comment: @Helic That assumption would be very much incorrect, as are a lot of other assumptions you seem to have made while writing this.  This code is very far from being able to be safely used from multiple threads.  You're probably better off just locking over the entirety of every single operation you do.  Writing lock-free or low lock code correctly is *very* hard.  Most assumptions about how C# programs word only in a single threaded context, you're relying on lots of things that just aren't there.

Comment: @Aron It will. `_list[_offset] = item;` isn't protected by a lock. One thread could be executing `_list[_offset] = item;` at the same time another thread just finished `_offset += 1;` where now `_offset` is equal to `_size`. Do you see what I mean?

Comment: @Aron, ToArray() should take what are in the array and make a copy?

Comment: @Sriramsakthivel items in the array may be overwrite if the offset is reset

Comment: @Helic it works by taking an Enumerator of the array, enumerating over the array and then creating a new array with references pointing to the same objects. If you are lucky it might shortcut to using array copy if Enumerable.ToArray is smart...which there is no guarantee it is.

Comment: @Aron I can reproduce what I just said. Try it yourself. Just run this code in multiple threads and see yourself `int i = 0; while (true){ list.Enqueu(i++); }` where list is `ConcurrentCircularFixedList<int>`

Comment: @Aron The example Sriram showed *would* throw, and for the reason he gave.  He described a possible situation in which the indexer would be called using an index outside of the bounds of the array.  And that's not to mention the possibility of items being dropped on the floor, or returned twice, which is quite plausible using this code.

Comment: This sounds like you want a lock-free immutable list that copies on write and is synchronization free on reads (I could write one if you'd like).  Your current implementation is both locking and not thread-safe.

Comment: @Zer0, can you give an example? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Here's a small version of a lock-free list that copies on write.  The performance characteristics should be clearly understood before using it.  It's expensive when you have many writers or the list is large.  Reads are synchronization free since the list is effectively immutable.  This could be improved in various ways of course but you get the idea.  In effect it sacrifices some memory pressure and slower writes for having zero cost reads.

```
public class CopyWriteList<T>
{
    private volatile List<T> list;

    public CopyWriteList()
    {
        list = new List<T>();
    }

    public CopyWriteList(int capacity)
    {
        list = new List<T>(capacity);
    }

    public T this[int index]
    {
        get { return list[index]; }
        set { Replace(x => x[index] = value); }
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        Replace(x => x.Clear());
    }

    public void Add(T item)
    {
        Replace(x => x.Add(item));
    }

    //Etc....

    private void Replace(Action<List<T>> action)
    {
        List<T> current;
        List<T> updated;
        do
        {
            current = list;
            updated = new List<T>(current);
            action(updated);
        } while (Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref list, updated, current) != current);
    }

    public List<T> GetSnapshot()
    {
        return list;
    }
}
```

Alternatively here's a fixed version of your code.  Note that there is added contention between both readers and writers.  Performance could suffer because of it (like the ever expensive context switching).

```
public class ConcurrentCircularFixedList<T>
{
    private readonly int _size;
    private int _offset;
    private readonly object _locker = new Object();
    private readonly T[] _list;

    public ConcurrentCircularFixedList(int size)
    {
        _size = size;
        _offset = 0;
        _list = new T[_size];
    }

    public int Enqueue(T item)
    {
        lock (_locker)
        {
            _list[_offset] = item;
            Debug.Write("B " + _offset);
            _offset += 1;
            if (_offset == _size)
                _offset = 0;
            Debug.Write("A " + _offset + "\n");
            return _offset;
        }
    }

    public T[] Dump()
    {
        lock (_locker)
            return _list.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. In Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref list, updated, current), why are list and current different? and what is the purpose making list volatile?

Comment: @Helic `list` and `current` may be different because of multithreading.  Imagine many threads "modifying" a `CopyWriteList` at once.  In most cases they will be the same and the CAS will succeed.  [Volatile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x13ttww7.aspx) is essentially a tip that tells the compiler not to optimize a variable for single threaded usage.

Comment: but List<T> is a reference type, should current and list store the same reference pointing to the same heap location?

Comment: @Helic I don't understand what you're asking.  If you don't understand the code for the `CopyWriteList` I would suggest not using it.  Stick with the fixed version of your code.

Comment: what I think is this code (List<T> current = list) creates the "current" variable on the stack together with "list" variable pointing to a List<T> object in the heap. So the value of "current" and "list" variable should always be the same as a reference (lets say XXX) to the List<T> object on the heap. And Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref list, updated, current) compares the value of list and current variable and they are both references XXX?

Comment: @Helic - Correct, assuming a single thread.  Normally, `current == list`.  Except when multiple threads are involved - which is the whole point of using a `lock` or the `Interlocked` operations.  So thread 1 sets `current = list`.  Then thread 2 updates `list` immediately afterwards.  Now on thread 1 `current != list`.  In other words, that CAS will only fail when another thread has succeeded in updating `list` concurrently.

Comment: "Then thread 2 updates list immediately afterwards", should thread 2 update the object on the heap and the reference (XXX) hold by list on stack remain the same?

Comment: @Helic I don't think you will understand this.  Perhaps you should research threading.  Anyways I'd advise you use the fixed version of your code and avoid the lock-free class entirely.

Comment: could you put your solution to the post?? I want to raise a question on the interlocked.CompareExchange for reference type as I don't quite understand how it works for reference types. Thanks.

Comment: I now understand your solution. if the second thread update the list variable to point to the new List<T> object pointed  by update variable, the first thread will keep looping and creating new List<T> objects for update variable until it gets a chance that reference hold by list matches the reference hold by its version of current and then update the list volatile variable to point to the new List<T> object on the heap referenced by its version of update variable on the stack.